# In Memory OLTP table is not visible in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio object explorer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2016, oltp, in-memory-oltp

I'm using SQL Server 2016 to learn about in-memory OLTP tables.

I created a database `mydatabase` and then run alter commands on this to create a file group:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase 
    ADD FILEGROUP [mydatabase_mod] CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA;
```

To create a container on this group:-

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase 
    ADD FILE (name = [mydatabase_dir], filename= 'e:\Learn\mydatabase_dir')  
        TO FILEGROUP mydatabase_mod;
```

These commands executed successfully, and then I created memory optimized  durable and non durable tables in this database; `mytable_durable` and `mytable_non_durable` are created successfully.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable_durable] 
( 
    c1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT=1000000),  
    c2 NCHAR(48) NOT NULL  
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA);  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable_non_durable] 
(  
    c1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH WITH   (BUCKET_COUNT=1000000),  
    c2 NCHAR(48) NOT NULL  
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY);
```

Now I want to see these two tables in object explorer in SQL Server 2016. They are not visible in my database under `mydatabase > Tables` node. How can I see them? Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

But if I run this

```
SELECT 
    name, object_id, type_desc, durability_desc, 
    temporal_type, temporal_type_desc
FROM 
    sys.Tables
```

I can see both tables. Please see following screenshot.

[image]

Is there any way where I can see them in object explorer?. Or is this default behaviour?

Comment: I was able to see the tables without issue. Did you try to refresh the tables folder or database folder?

Comment: Yes @dco. I restarted the management studio also but no use.

Comment: what version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      13.0.15700.28
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      13.0.1700.68
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.18618
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.9600

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution was to make sure to open the correct SSMS version. I installed version 17.1 from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms
and run
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I see the issue here is the version you are using. You are using SSMS 16.3

Please make sure you use the latest version of SSMS. Current version is 16.5.3 as of this writing. Download it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). Please take note that Microsoft is doing a monthly patch/updates of SSMS.

Comment: what version are you using? Please query: `SELECT @@VERSION`